# Why mouseenter and mouseleave work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, dom-events

I want to understand why `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events work on mobile.

I am trying to create a tooltip that hovers on desktop but is clickable on mobile and at first, I just went ahead and implemented those events on VueJS but for some reason when I tested it on mobile, it automatically switched to clickable events. Also, it automatically handles the blur event on mobile (clicking outside it, would close the tooltip)

I could only think of three reasons, either:

- Browser automatically switched the events
- Vue is doing the switching of events
- DOM is doing the switching

I also created a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouseenter-mouseleave-sample-g8h36) to play with.

---

EDIT:

I just tried replicating it on vanilla JS, and same behavior.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouseenter-mouseleave-sample-js-r40q0).

Based on this, is this safe to continue with this?

I couldn't find any docs that stated this behavior.

Comment: hey! did you find an answer to your question? is it safe to use "mouseenter" on mobile instead of "click"?

Comment: @Dr.FreddyDimethyltryptamine Sorry I don't, I just went with the mouseenter/mouseleave approach, and never had an issue. I guess it's safe to use it. Still hoping for someone to explain it deeply for me.